Finding order without the item in one of the multiple rows
I'm trying to write a query to find what orders don't have the wipes item.



ORDER ID
ORDER NUMBER
ITEM
ITEM ID




00FF6248
2404902
Sponge
87f5


00FF6248
2404902
Soap
4D1C


1F210331
2404905
Gloves
2fb0


1F210331
2404905
Paper
4dbb


1F210331
2404905
Bags
ad1e


6112f371
2404904
Wipes
B94A


6112f371
2404904
Detergent
62DF


6112f371
2404904
Soap
4D1C



I tried doing a query WHERE ITEM <> 'WIPES'and GROUP BY ORDER ID (not sure if that is the right path) but I'm still getting all the orders.
The desired outcome would be:
ORDER ID
--------
00FF6248
1F210331

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.
This is what I have. I feel like is a simple query but I guess I just don't know yet how to approach this kind of queries yet.
SELECT DISTINCT ORDERID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ITEM <> 'WIPES'


Add a tag for the RDBMS that you use. (hover the tag to see the info) ... and also add the attempted query to the question.

What's your rdbms? and could you share what have you tried?

Thank you for your comments. I have added the information requested.

with T as (
  select ORDER_ID from T1
where UPPER(ITEM) <> 'WIPES'
) select distinct ORDER_ID from T;

or
with T as (
  select ORDER_ID from T1
where UPPER(ITEM) <> 'WIPES'
) select ORDER_ID from T group by ORDER_ID;

or
select ORDER_ID from 
  (select * from T1 where UPPER(ITEM) <> 'WIPES') t
  group by ORDER_ID;

check output: https://dbfiddle.uk/AnH1oygN

If I understand corrctly you can use DISTINCT with NOT EXISTS to obtains your expected result.
NOT EXISTS with subquery would assist with us filter ORDER ID which is not equal WIPES.
The main query selects distinct [ORDER ID] values from the table and filters out orders that contain the item 'Wipes' in subquery. This will give you the desired outcome, which is a list of orders that do not include the item 'Wipes'.
SELECT DISTINCT [ORDER ID]
FROM ORDERS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ORDERS tt
    WHERE t1.[ORDER ID] = tt.[ORDER ID] and tt.ITEM = 'Wipes'
)

here is a sample from  sqlfiddle

You are on the right track to use GROUP BY and check that ITEM is not Wipes.
You just need a conditional count in the HAVING clause rather than using WHERE:
SELECT [ORDER ID]
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY [ORDER ID]
HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN ITEM = 'Wipes' THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY [ORDER ID];

Note: SQL Server as RDBMS will show a warning for that query:

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
operation.

You can just ignore that. The query is fine and will produce the expected result. The warning says that COUNT does not include NULL values. That's the correct behaviour and I have no clue why SQL Server thinks a warning should be shown in that case. No other RDBMS would show such a warning at all.
Anyway, if you urgently get rid of that warning, you can use SUM with ELSE 0 instead, then no warning will appear:
SELECT [ORDER ID]
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY [ORDER ID]
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN ITEM = 'Wipes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY [ORDER ID];

A completely other way to get the expected result is EXCEPT. First fetch all ORDER ID, then only those without ITEM as Wipes:
SELECT [ORDER ID]
FROM yourtable
EXCEPT
SELECT [ORDER ID]
FROM yourtable
WHERE ITEM = 'Wipes'
ORDER BY [ORDER ID]

I like this option because of the great readability, but it might be slow because it selects twice from the table. Just try out.
See this sample fiddle
